# Find all $n \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $X^3 + Y^3 = n$ has at least one and only finitely many rational solutions.

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

I have tried some case about this question such as $n=9$.

And I find out when $n=9$, $X^3+Y^3=9$ has infinite rational solutions. This can be proved by using elliptic curves and geometric constructions. We can find tangent line of the initial solution and then determine if this tangent line intersect with the curve or not.

But this method can only use when you know the value of n I think. I have no idea how to find out all the value of $n$ which satisfy the requirement.

Any hint or solution is appreciated. Thanks.

---

Actually there is a previous question for this question:

"Prove that the torsion points of elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ are finitely many."

My solution for this question is "By Mordell-Weil thoerem, $E(\mathbb{Q})$ is a finitely generated abelian group, thus by the structure theorem of finitely generated abelian groups, the torsion part of $E(\mathbb{Q})$  is a finite group."

Our teacher gave me this comment, "You can use the technique of Mordell-Weil thoerem to prove that rational torsion points are finite, don't apply Mordell-Weil thoerem directly. Proving that torsion points are finite is far easier than the Mordell-Weil thoerem." But I have no idea how to use the technique of Mordell-Weil thoerem to prove that rational torsion points are finite.

Helping on this question or the question about find all $n$ is appreciated. Thanks.

---

I got a hint from my teacher but I still cannot figure out. So I decide to post the hint here.

Hint: The general problem is this: given a rational elliptic curve of "family", how to find all elliptic curves of this family with rank 0 and non-trivial torsion points?

Guess: there are only a limited number of good families, and there are effective algorithms.

Question: what is a good family?

Case: $Y^3+Z^3=n$

What is the method for this example?

Comment: Do you mean finite amount of rational solutions?

Comment: Yes, and $n \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $a, b, c$  be non-zero rational numbers. Then the genus 1 surface $C: ax^3 + by^3 + c=0$ has infinitely many non-zero rational points if and only if the Mordel-Weil group of the elliptic curve $Y^2 = X^3 + 432abc$ has rank $> 0$.

In other words,  if $C$ has a non-zero rational point, one can derive infinitely many other non-zero rational points.

Comment: Yes. But I cannot see the requirement of $n$. Can you explain a little more explicit？

Comment: Since we don’t have $Y^2$

Answer (score 3):

The question seems asks for a "pattern" for all $n$, such that there are only finitely many rational solution of the (affine) equation:
$$
\tag{$*$}
X^3+ Y^3 = n\ .
$$
(Keywords: *Sylvester's conjecture*.)

This answer cites some results, and shows that even in the special case of a prime $n$ things are nontrivial. Using sage two tables are plotted, one for the first few integers $n\ge 1$, one for the case $n=p$ prime congruent to $1$ modulo nine.

---

There are some articles written on this topic:

- (RV,Z) [Which primes are sums of two cubes? Fernando Rodriguez-Villegas and Don Zagier](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/mpim/95-61/fulltext.pdf)
- (D,V,1) [Sylvester's problem and mock Heegner points, Samit Dasgupta and John Voight](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Edasgupta/papers/Sylvester.pdf)
- (D,V,2) [Heegner points and Sylvester’s conjecture, Samit Dasgupta and John Voight](https://math.dartmouth.edu/%7Ejvoight/articles/mockheegner-clay-proceedings-fixed-errata-071017.pdf)

This papers have a special research target, consider the case when $n$ is directly related to a prime $p$ (with further restrictions), e.g. $n=p, p^2, 2p, 2p^2, 25p^2$. The introductions are informative for the present question.
The situation for *prime* values of $n$ is the common research theme. This answer merely uses computer aid, [sage](https://www.sagemath.org), to support the results.

I am citing now from the paper on mock Heegner points, (D,V,1)...

> **Conjecture:** (Sylvester, Selmer) Let $E_n$ be the elliptic curve with (affine) equation $X^3+Y^3=n$. If $n=p$ is a prime, and $p=4,7,8$ modulo nine, then the rank of $E_p(\Bbb Q)$ is positive.

An explicit $3$-descent argument by Satgé shows:

> $$\operatorname{rank}E_p(\Bbb Q)\le\begin{cases}
> 0 &\text{ for }p\equiv 2, 5&&\text{ modulo nine,}\\
> 1 &\text{ for }p\equiv 4, 7,8&&\text{ modulo nine,}\\
> 2 &\text{ for }p\equiv 1&&\text{ modulo nine,}
> \end{cases}$$

(This covers only the case of a prime $n$.)

The case $p=1$ modulo nine shows that from situation to situation,
the special arithmetic of the corresponding elliptic curve determines if we have rank $0$ or rank $2$. (The sign of the functional equation for $L(E_p,\cdot)$ is plus in this case.)

In this answer there is only some computer algebra evidence for the first
few natural values of $n$ up to $200$. For such values of $n$
the code in the sequel realizes the following "plan". It starts with the curve $E_n$ with equation $X^3+Y^3=n$, brings it into the Weierstraß form $E'_n$ with equation $y^2=x^3-432n^2$, then asks for the rank and the generators of $E'(\Bbb Q)$, and - if any - brings them back to $E_n(\Bbb Q)$. The data is collected in a string that is suitable to be copy-pasted here inside an array block.

---

The passage from $E_n$ to $E'_n$ is as follows:
$$
\begin{aligned}
X &=\frac{36n-y}{6x}\ , & Y&=\frac{36n+y}{6x}\ ,\\[2mm]
x &=\frac{12n}{X+Y}\ ,& y &=-36n\cdot\frac{X-Y}{X+Y}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

---

Let us check that the above birational maps $(x,y)\to(X,Y)$ and $(X,Y)\to(x,y)$ are well defined, and inverse to each other.
(Please skip if this feels too explicit.)

- We start with $(x,y)$ satisfying $y^2=x^3-432n^2$. Then:
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  X^3+Y^3&=\frac 1{216x^3}((36n-y)^3+(36n+y)^3
  \\
  &=\frac 2{216x^3}((36n)^3 +3(36n)y^2)
  \\
  &=\frac2{216(432n^2+y^2)}\cdot (36n)\cdot ((36n)^2+3y^2)
  \\
  &=n\ .
  \end{aligned}
  $$
- Assume now $X^3+Y^3=n$, then:
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  x^3-y^2
  &=(12n)^3\cdot \frac  {(X+Y)^3} - (36n)^2\frac  {(X-Y)^2}{(X+Y)^2}
  \\
  &=(12n)^2\cdot \frac 1{(X+Y)^3}(12n -9(X-Y)^2(X+Y))
  \\
  &=(12n)^2\cdot 3\cdot \frac {(X^3 + Y^3)+3XY(X+Y)}{4n-3(X^3 + Y^3)+3XY(X+Y)}
  \\
  &=(12n)^2\cdot 3\cdot \frac {n+3XY(X+Y)}{n+3XY(X+Y)}
  \\
  &=(12n)^2\cdot 3=432n^2\ .
  \end{aligned}
  $$
- It remains to check that the formulas for the passage between the $(X,Y)$-world and the $(x,y)$-world are inverse to each other. We start with the formulas for $(X,Y)$ and compute successively $\displaystyle X+Y=2\cdot \frac{36n}{6x}=\frac{12n}x$, $\displaystyle X-Y=-2\cdot \frac{y}{6x}=\frac{12n}x$, $\displaystyle \frac{12n}{X+Y}=x$, and $\displaystyle -(36n)\cdot{X-Y}{X+Y}= -(36n)\cdot\frac{-2\cdot y/(6x)}{-2\cdot(36n)/(6x)}=y
  $. The other direction is similar.

---

The code implementing the "plan" above uses the above formulas to pass from the Selmer curve $E_n$ to the elliptic curve in  Weierstraß form $E'_n$. (And computes rank and generators in this world, the world where sage implements them.)

```
s = ''    # latex string to be inserted in an array block

def get_selmer_point(n, P):
    """Here P = (x, y) is a point on y² = x³ - 432n²"""
    x, y = P.xy()
    X, Y = (36*n - y)/6/x, (36*n + y)/6/x
    denom = gcd(X.denominator(), Y.denominator())
    return (X*denom, Y*denom, denom)

for n in [1..120]:
    print(f'Computations for n = {n}')
    E = EllipticCurve(QQ, [0, -432*n^2])
    print(f'E = {E}')
    try:
        r = E.rank(only_use_mwrank=False)
        print(f'\tRANK = {r}')
        gens = [get_selmer_point(n, P) for P in E.gens()]
        gens_info = '\\ ,\\ '.join([str(Q) for Q in gens])
    except:
       print(f'*** rank computation error, using analytic rank... ***')
       r = E.analytic_rank()
       gens_info = '?' if r > 0 else ''
    
    prime_info = '\\text{PRIME}' if n.is_prime() else ''
    s += f'{n} & {n%9} & {prime_info} & {r} & {gens_info}\\\\\\hline\n'

print(s)
```

The results are presented in the following latex array block:
$$
\begin{array}{|r||r|l|c|l|}
\hline
n & n[9] & \text{prime?} & r & \text{generators $(X,Y,Z)$ with }X^3+Y^3=nZ^3\\\hline\hline
1 & 1 &  & 0 & \\\hline
2 & 2 & \text{PRIME} & 0 & \\\hline
3 & 3 & \text{PRIME} & 0 & \\\hline
4 & 4 &  & 0 & \\\hline
5 & 5 & \text{PRIME} & 0 & \\\hline
6 & 6 &  & 1 & (17, 37, 21)\\\hline
7 & 7 & \text{PRIME} & 1 & (-1, 2, 1)\\\hline
8 & 8 &  & 0 & \\\hline
9 & 0 &  & 1 & (1, 2, 1)\\\hline
10 & 1 &  & 0 & \\\hline
11 & 2 & \text{PRIME} & 0 & \\\hline
12 & 3 &  & 1 & (19, 89, 39)\\\hline
13 & 4 & \text{PRIME} & 1 & (2, 7, 3)\\\hline
14 & 5 &  & 0 & \\\hline
15 & 6 &  & 1 & (397, 683, 294)\\\hline
16 & 7 &  & 0 & \\\hline
17 & 8 & \text{PRIME} & 1 & (-1, 18, 7)\\\hline
18 & 0 &  & 0 & \\\hline
19 & 1 & \text{PRIME} & 2 & (3, 5, 2)\ ,\ (1, 8, 3)\\\hline
20 & 2 &  & 1 & (1, 19, 7)\\\hline
21 & 3 &  & 0 & \\\hline
22 & 4 &  & 1 & (17299, 25469, 9954)\\\hline
23 & 5 & \text{PRIME} & 0 & \\\hline
24 & 6 &  & 0 & \\\hline
25 & 7 &  & 0 & \\\hline
26 & 8 &  & 1 & (-1, 3, 1)\\\hline
27 & 0 &  & 0 & \\\hline
28 & 1 &  & 1 & (1, 3, 1)\\\hline
29 & 2 & \text{PRIME} & 0 & \\\hline
30 & 3 &  & 2 & (107, 163, 57)\ ,\ (-19, 289, 93)\\\hline
31 & 4 & \text{PRIME} & 1 & (-65, 137, 42)\\\hline
32 & 5 &  & 0 & \\\hline
33 & 6 &  & 1 & (523, 1853, 582)\\\hline
34 & 7 &  & 1 & (-359, 631, 182)\\\hline
35 & 8 &  & 1 & (2, 3, 1)\\\hline
36 & 0 &  & 0 & \\\hline
37 & 1 & \text{PRIME} & 2 & (18, 19, 7)\ ,\ (-1, 10, 3)\\\hline
38 & 2 &  & 0 & \\\hline
39 & 3 &  & 0 & \\\hline
40 & 4 &  & 0 & \\\hline
41 & 5 & \text{PRIME} & 0 & \\\hline
42 & 6 &  & 1 & (-71, 449, 129)\\\hline
43 & 7 & \text{PRIME} & 1 & (1, 7, 2)\\\hline
44 & 8 &  & 0 & \\\hline
45 & 0 &  & 0 & \\\hline
46 & 1 &  & 0 & \\\hline
47 & 2 & \text{PRIME} & 0 & \\\hline
48 & 3 &  & 1 & (34, 74, 21)\\\hline
49 & 4 &  & 1 & (-2, 11, 3)\\\hline
50 & 5 &  & 1 & (-11267, 23417, 6111)\\\hline
51 & 6 &  & 1 & (62641, 730511, 197028)\\\hline
52 & 7 &  & 0 & \\\hline
53 & 8 & \text{PRIME} & 1 & (-1819, 1872, 217)\\\hline
54 & 0 &  & 0 & \\\hline
55 & 1 &  & 0 & \\\hline
56 & 2 &  & 1 & (-2, 4, 1)\\\hline
57 & 3 &  & 0 & \\\hline
58 & 4 &  & 1 & (-14653, 28747, 7083)\\\hline
59 & 5 & \text{PRIME} & 0 & \\\hline
60 & 6 &  & 0 & \\\hline
61 & 7 & \text{PRIME} & 1 & (-4, 5, 1)\\\hline
62 & 8 &  & 1 & (7, 11, 3)\\\hline
63 & 0 &  & 1 & (-1, 4, 1)\\\hline
64 & 1 &  & 0 & \\\hline
65 & 2 &  & 2 & (197, 323, 86)\ ,\ (1, 4, 1)\\\hline
66 & 3 &  & 0 & \\\hline
67 & 4 & \text{PRIME} & 1 & (1208, 5353, 1323)\\\hline
68 & 5 &  & 1 & (-472663, 2538163, 620505)\\\hline
69 & 6 &  & 1 & (-10441, 15409, 3318)\\\hline
70 & 7 &  & 1 & (17, 53, 13)\\\hline
71 & 8 & \text{PRIME} & 1 & (-126, 197, 43)\\\hline
72 & 0 &  & 1 & (2, 4, 1)\\\hline
73 & 1 & \text{PRIME} & 0 & \\\hline
74 & 2 &  & 0 & \\\hline
75 & 3 &  & 1 & (-11951, 17351, 3606)\\\hline
76 & 4 &  & 0 & \\\hline
77 & 5 &  & 0 & \\\hline
78 & 6 &  & 1 & (53, 5563, 1302)\\\hline
79 & 7 & \text{PRIME} & 1 & (-4, 13, 3)\\\hline
80 & 8 &  & 0 & \\\hline
81 & 0 &  & 0 & \\\hline
82 & 1 &  & 0 & \\\hline
83 & 2 & \text{PRIME} & 0 & \\\hline
84 & 3 &  & 1 & (323, 433, 111)\\\hline
85 & 4 &  & 1 & (-2404889, 2570129, 330498)\\\hline
86 & 5 &  & 2 & (60877, 106307, 25506)\ ,\ (5, 13, 3)\\\hline
87 & 6 &  & 1 & (1176498611, -907929611, 216266610)\\\hline
88 & 7 &  & 0 & \\\hline
89 & 8 & \text{PRIME} & 1 & (36, 53, 13)\\\hline
90 & 0 &  & 1 & (-431, 1241, 273)\\\hline
91 & 1 &  & 2 & (3, 4, 1)\ ,\ (23, 94, 21)\\\hline
92 & 2 &  & 1 & (-3547, 25903, 5733)\\\hline
93 & 3 &  & 0 & \\\hline
94 & 4 &  & 1 & (15642626656646177, -15616184186396177, 590736058375050)\\\hline
95 & 5 &  & 0 & \\\hline
96 & 6 &  & 1 & (38, 178, 39)\\\hline
97 & 7 & \text{PRIME} & 1 & (-5, 14, 3)\\\hline
98 & 8 &  & 1 & (-3, 5, 1)\\\hline
99 & 0 &  & 0 & \\\hline
100 & 1 &  & 0 & \\\hline
101 & 2 & \text{PRIME} & 0 & \\\hline
102 & 3 &  & 0 & \\\hline
103 & 4 & \text{PRIME} & 1 & (-349, 592, 117)\\\hline
104 & 5 &  & 1 & (4, 14, 3)\\\hline
105 & 6 &  & 1 & (3527, 4033, 1014)\\\hline
106 & 7 &  & 1 & (-140131, 165889, 25767)\\\hline
107 & 8 & \text{PRIME} & 1 & (17, 90, 19)\\\hline
108 & 0 &  & 0 & \\\hline
109 & 1 & \text{PRIME} & 0 & \\\hline
110 & 2 &  & 2 & (251, 629, 134)\ ,\ (-71, 181, 37)\\\hline
111 & 3 &  & 0 & \\\hline
112 & 4 &  & 0 & \\\hline
113 & 5 & \text{PRIME} & 0 & \\\hline
114 & 6 &  & 1 & (-901, 9109, 1878)\\\hline
115 & 7 &  & 1 & (-2741617, 5266097, 1029364)\\\hline
116 & 8 &  & 0 & \\\hline
117 & 0 &  & 1 & (-2, 5, 1)\\\hline
118 & 1 &  & 0 & \\\hline
119 & 2 &  & 0 & \\\hline
120 & 3 &  & 1 & (397, 683, 147)\\\hline
121 & 4 &  & 0 & \\\hline
122 & 5 &  & 0 & \\\hline
123 & 6 &  & 1 & (184223499139, 10183412861, 37045412880)\\\hline
124 & 7 &  & 2 & (-1, 5, 1)\ ,\ (-443, 479, 57)\\\hline
125 & 8 &  & 0 & \\\hline
126 & 0 &  & 2 & (1, 5, 1)\ ,\ (-121, 127, 13)\\\hline
127 & 1 & \text{PRIME} & 2 & (-251, 378, 67)\ ,\ (-6, 7, 1)\\\hline
128 & 2 &  & 0 & \\\hline
129 & 3 &  & 0 & \\\hline
130 & 4 &  & 1 & (52954777, 33728183, 11285694)\\\hline
131 & 5 & \text{PRIME} & 0 & \\\hline
132 & 6 &  & 2 & (-901, 2089, 399)\ ,\ (-29503, 39007, 6342)\\\hline
133 & 7 &  & 1 & (2, 5, 1)\\\hline
134 & 8 &  & 1 & (7, 9, 2)\\\hline
135 & 0 &  & 0 & \\\hline
136 & 1 &  & 1 & (-2, 36, 7)\\\hline
137 & 2 & \text{PRIME} & 0 & \\\hline
138 & 3 &  & 0 & \\\hline
139 & 4 & \text{PRIME} & 1 & (-7, 16, 3)\\\hline
140 & 5 &  & 1 & (6623, 27397, 5301)\\\hline
141 & 6 &  & 1 & (53579249, -52310249, 4230030)\\\hline
142 & 7 &  & 1 & (2454839, 1858411, 530595)\\\hline
143 & 8 &  & 1 & (15, 73, 14)\\\hline
144 & 0 &  & 0 & \\\hline
145 & 1 &  & 0 & \\\hline
146 & 2 &  & 0 & \\\hline
147 & 3 &  & 0 & \\\hline
148 & 4 &  & 0 & \\\hline
149 & 5 & \text{PRIME} & 0 & \\\hline
150 & 6 &  & 0 & \\\hline
\end{array}
$$
There is no predictible "simple rule" to see when the rank is zero!

---

Here comes a further table, containing only the cases of a prime $n$, of the shape $n=p$ with $p$ congruent to $1$ modulo $9$. Citing from the paper on mock Heegner points, (D,V,1) ...

> ... for $p\equiv 1$  (mod $9$), the Birch–Swinnerton-Dyer (BSD) conjecture predicts that $\operatorname{rank}E_p(\Bbb Q) = 0$ or $2$, **depending on $p$ in a nontrivial way**. This case was investigated by Rodriguez-Villegas and Zagier [10]: they give three methods to determine for a given prime $p$ whether or not $\operatorname{rank}E_p(\Bbb Q) = 0$.

Which is this non-trivial way? We have to look into (RV,Z).
For the rank equal to zero, as asked in the OP, we expect a non-vanishing of
$$
L(E'_p,1)=
\frac {\sqrt 3\; \Gamma\left(\frac 1p\right)^3}{2\pi\; p^{1/3}}\cdot
S_p\ ,\qquad
S_p=\operatorname{Trace}(\alpha_p)=\operatorname{Trace}^2(\beta_P)\in\Bbb Z
\ ,
$$
where $S_p$ is written alternatively as first two powers of the the trace of some algebraic numbers $\alpha_p,\beta_P$ of high degree (increasing with $p$), see *loc. cit.* for their definition. In §5 of (RV,Z) it is shown that
$|S_p|<p/2$, so it is enought to know $S_p$ modulo $p$, and moreover, the vanishing of $S_p$ becomes equivalent to its vanishing modulo $p$. And we have modulo $p$
$$
S_p\equiv \text{(known factor)}\cdot A_{2(p-1)/9}\equiv \text{(known factor)}\cdot B^2_{2(p-1)/9}\ ,
$$
where the known factor above does not vanish, and the integer coefficients $A_k=B_k^2$ are extracted from the series representations:
$$
\begin{aligned}
{}_2F_1\left(\frac 13,\frac 13\ ;\ \frac 23\ ;\ x\right)
&=\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac {A_k}{(3k)!}\; T^k\ ,\\
(1-x)^{1/24}
{}_2F_1\left(\frac 13,\frac 13\ ;\ \frac 23\ ;\ x\right)^{1/2}
&=\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac {B_k}{(3k)!}\; \left(\frac{-T}2\right)^k\ ,\\
&\qquad\text{ where }\\
T
&=
x\cdot
\frac
{{}_2F_1\left(\frac 23,\frac 23\ ;\ \frac 43\ ;\ x\right)^3}
{{}_2F_1\left(\frac 13,\frac 13\ ;\ \frac 23\ ;\ x\right)^3}
\end{aligned}
$$
So for the case $n=p$ prime (and $n=p^2$) in the "complicated" case of $p\equiv 1$ modulo nine, (RV,Z) provides an answer. (Compute the corresponding coefficient $A_k=B_k^2$, take it modulo $p$, see if this residue does not vanish.)

I am trying to compute some relevant data in a table.
For the first few such primes $p\equiv 1[9]$  we have in the table the rank,
computed individually, together with the data for $S_p$ from the above formulas.

```
def A(k, p):
    R.<t> = PolynomialRing(GF(p))
    f, F, n = R(1), t^2, 1    # F is f_n(t) with notations from (RV,Z)
    while n < 3*k:
        f, F, = F, (1-t^3)*diff(F, t) + (2*n+1)*t^2*F - n^2*t*f
        n += 1
    return F(0)

def S(p):
    if not p.is_prime():    return
    k = (p - 1)/9
    if k not in ZZ:    return
    k = ZZ(k)
    F = GF(p)
    Sp = A(2*k, p) * F(-3)^(3*k -3) * prod([F(j) for j in [1..3*k]])^2
    return Sp.lift_centered()

s = ''
for p in primes(3000):
    if p % 9 != 1:    continue
    print(f'Computations for p = {p}')
    E = EllipticCurve(QQ, [0, -432*p^2])
    print(f'E = {E}')
    try:
        r = E.rank(only_use_mwrank=False)
        print(f'\tRANK = {r}')
        gens = [get_selmer_point(p, P) for P in E.gens()]
        gens_info = '\\ ,\\ '.join([str(Q) for Q in gens])
    except:
       print(f'*** rank computation error, using analytic rank... ***')
       r = E.analytic_rank()
       gens_info = '?' if r > 0 else ''
    s += f'{p} & {r} & {gens_info} & {S(p)}\\\\\\hline\n'
print(s)
```

Results:

$$
\begin{array}{|r||r|l||c|}
\hline
n & r & \text{generators $(X,Y,Z)$ with }X^3+Y^3=nZ^3 & S_p\\\hline\hline
19 & 2 & (3, 5, 2)\ ,\ (1, 8, 3) & 0\\\hline
37 & 2 & (18, 19, 7)\ ,\ (-1, 10, 3) & 0\\\hline
73 & 0 &  & 1\\\hline
109 & 0 &  & 1\\\hline
127 & 2 & (-251, 378, 67)\ ,\ (-6, 7, 1) & 0\\\hline
163 & 2 & (73, 90, 19)\ ,\ (-3, 11, 2) & 0\\\hline
181 & 0 &  & 1\\\hline
199 & 0 &  & 1\\\hline
271 & 2 & (-216, 487, 73)\ ,\ (-9, 10, 1) & 0\\\hline
307 & 0 &  & 1\\\hline
379 & 2 & (-7, 15, 2)\ ,\ (-1007, 1386, 163) & 0\\\hline
397 & 2 & (37, 360, 49)\ ,\ (-11, 12, 1) & 0\\\hline
433 & 2 & (35, 37, 6)\ ,\ (181, 252, 37) & 0\\\hline
487 & 0 &  & 1\\\hline
523 & 2 & (-269, 792, 97)\ ,\ (-9, 17, 2) & 0\\\hline
541 & 0 &  & 1\\\hline
577 & 0 &  & 1\\\hline
613 & 0 &  & 1\\\hline
631 & 2 & (-3761, 4886, 465)\ ,\ (-14, 15, 1) & 0\\\hline
739 & 0 &  & 4\\\hline
757 & 0 &  & 1\\\hline
811 & 0 &  & 1\\\hline
829 & 2 & (393, 607, 70)\ ,\ (-2591, 3420, 301) & 0\\\hline
883 & 2 & (-1482390, 5820569, 603347)\ ,\ (-13, 21, 2) & 0\\\hline
919 & 2 & (216, 703, 73)\ ,\ (-17, 18, 1) & 0\\\hline
937 & 2 & (-26, 35, 3)\ ,\ (939188250, -799690501, 69681803) & 0\\\hline
991 & 0 &  & 4\\\hline
1009 & 0 &  & 1\\\hline
1063 & 2 & (-28, 37, 3)\ ,\ (-22247, 23310, 1159) & 0\\\hline
1117 & 0 &  & 1\\\hline
1153 & 0 &  & 1\\\hline
1171 & 2 & (25, 39, 4)\ ,\ (-233, 1404, 133) & 0\\\hline
1279 & 0 &  & 1\\\hline
1297 & 0 &  & 1\\\hline
1423 & 0 &  & 1\\\hline
1459 & 2 & (48014927, 19750897, 4329444)\ ,\ (-10440, 11899, 721) & 0\\\hline
1531 & 2 & (19, 45, 4)\ ,\ (-5309, 6840, 481) & 0\\\hline
1549 & 0 &  & 1\\\hline
1567 & 2 & (307, 1260, 109)\ ,\ (-35, 44, 3) & 0\\\hline
1621 & 2 & (631, 990, 91)\ ,\ (-58445, 65006, 3591) & 0\\\hline
1657 & 2 & (1, 71, 6)\ ,\ (-1530, 3187, 259) & 0\\\hline
1693 & 0 &  & 1\\\hline
1747 & 0 &  & 4\\\hline
1783 & 0 &  & 1\\\hline
1801 & 2 & (594, 1207, 103)\ ,\ (-1, 73, 6) & 0\\\hline
1873 & 0 &  & 4\\\hline
1999 & 0 &  & 4\\\hline
2017 & 0 &  & 1\\\hline
2053 & 0 &  & 1\\\hline
2089 & 2 & (13938, 28937, 2345)\ ,\ (396, 1693, 133) & 0\\\hline
2143 & 0 &  & 1\\\hline
2161 & 0 &  & 1\\\hline
2179 & 0 &  & 1\\\hline
2251 & 0 &  & 4\\\hline
2269 & 2 & (-2771, 5040, 361)\ ,\ (-27, 28, 1) & 0\\\hline
2287 & 0 &  & 1\\\hline
2341 & 0 &  & 4\\\hline
2377 & 0 &  & 4\\\hline
2467 & 0 &  & 4\\\hline
2503 & 0 &  & 1\\\hline
2521 & 0 &  & 1\\\hline
2539 & 2 & (-25, 33, 2)\ ,\ (-9467, 12006, 703) & 0\\\hline
2557 & 2 & (-3762, 6319, 427)\ ,\ (-46, 55, 3) & 0\\\hline
2593 & 0 &  & 4\\\hline
2647 & 2 & (1009, 1638, 127)\ ,\ (-12740, 19599, 1273) & 0\\\hline
2683 & 0 &  & 1\\\hline
2719 & 0 &  & 1\\\hline
2791 & 2 & (-30, 31, 1)\ ,\ (-296496, 299287, 6433) & 0\\\hline
2917 & 0 &  & 1\\\hline
2953 & 0 &  & 1\\\hline
2971 & 0 &  & 4\\\hline
\end{array}
$$
And indeed, we have solutions (and explicit generators above), iff the $S_p$ vanishes. (The computed values for $S_p$ are among $0^2, 1^2, 2^2$.)